# CSS hover using Outline not working

Tags: html, css, overlay, border, outline

I'm trying to overlay an Outline over my image using css but the outline isn't showing up. If I replace the outline with a background-color it works fine, but it doesn't achieve the framing affect I'm going for. I also tried using borders but that increased the size of the div so it doesn't work either. I need the overlay div to be 100% height and width because the image size is dynamic.

```
<figure class="visual-thumbnail" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
<div class="img-info"></div>

        <a href="http://innovationinhr.com/apploi/?p=351" class="thumbnail">
        <img width="326" height="434" src="http://innovationinhr.com/apploi/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/unknown-326x434.jpeg" class="attachment-visual-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Sharif">        



        </a>
    </figure>


figure{ display:block;overflow: hidden;
position: relative;width:326px;height:435px;}


.img-info {
outline: solid black 25px;
background-color: black;
left: 0;
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
height: 100%;
}
.visual-thumbnail:hover .img-info{
opacity:.5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P4nEK/1/

Any reason the outline wouldn't be showing up?

Answer (score 1):

The outline is invisible, because outlines appear *outside* of the element. In this case, since the element (`div`) is as large as the parent (`figure`), it would have appeared outside the `figure`. But the `figure` has `overflow:hidden`.

Solution: remove both `overflow:hidden`s from the figure. Or place the `div` in such a position that its outline falls inside the `figure`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem, as MrLister noted, is that you have `overflow:hidden` on the figure.  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4enRS/) shows the basic idea you wanted working.

As another note, z-index only affects elements in the same context.  [Here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) is a really good article about it.  So I think what you are *really* trying to do is put the other div under the image and make it show a border on hover.  In order to do that, they must be drawn in the same context which means they all need to have the `position` attribute.  Here is a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/P4nEK/6/